# OnClick Listener to apply to the clicked card and not another one on the adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

When I click on a given card, it opens like the card below it on a new activity and not that specific card.

For example, if I click the first card after the facebook native ad, it opens the details for the third card and so on. Here is my class.

*Is there a way I can get to open the exact card I click on to my next Activity?*

```
public void setClickListener(View.OnClickListener callback) {
    mClickListener = callback;
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) 
{
    if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
        View inflatedView;
        if (AD_FORM == 3) {
            inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.ad_unit, viewGroup, false);
        }
        else {
            inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.ad_unit2, viewGroup, false);
        }
        return new AdHolder(inflatedView);
    }
    else {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.feed_item, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder personViewHolder = new PersonViewHolder(inflatedView);
        personViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mClickListener.onClick(view);
            }
        });
        return personViewHolder;
    }
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) 
{
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == AD_TYPE) {
        if (mAd != null) {
            ((AdHolder)holder).bindView(mAd);
        }
        else if (mAds != null && mAds.isLoaded()) {
            mAd = mAds.nextNativeAd();
            ((AdHolder)holder).bindView(mAd);
        }
        else {
            ((AdHolder)holder).bindView(null);
        }
    }
    else {
        i = position;
        if (i != 0) {
            i--;
        }
        String cover = "https://www.stanzascoop.com/covers/"+ persons.get(i).photoId;
        String avi = "https://www.stanzascoop.com/avis/"+ persons.get(i).photo;
        final String views = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(persons.get(i).viewcount) + " scoops";
        ((PersonViewHolder)holder).uploadUser.setText(persons.get(i).username);
        ((PersonViewHolder)holder).uploadDate.setText(persons.get(i).uploaddate);
        ((PersonViewHolder)holder).personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        ((PersonViewHolder)holder).personAge.setText("by "+ persons.get(i).age);
        ((PersonViewHolder)holder).viewCount.setText(views);
        context = mContext;
        Picasso.with(context).load(cover).transform(new RoundedTransformation(0, 0)).fit().into(((PersonViewHolder)holder).personPhoto);
        Picasso.with(context).load(avi).transform(new RoundedTransformation(100, 0)).fit().into(((PersonViewHolder)holder).authorPhoto);

        ((PersonViewHolder)holder).setClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int s = getItemCount();
                int pos = ((PersonViewHolder)holder).getAdapterPosition();
                Log.e(TAG, "POS: "+ ((PersonViewHolder)holder).getItemId());
                openLyric(persons.get(i).name, persons.get(i).content, persons.get(i).age, persons.get(i).photoId, views, persons.get(i).lurl);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It should be pretty easy to find the mistake by debugging so you can track what is being called and check why this is the case.

Comment: Okay let me try that